C++, how undefined variable works
The problem
I'm trying to understand how C++ compilers handle undefined variables, and I've written the following code :
int test() {
  bool b; //undefined

  if(b){return 1;}
  else {return 2;}
  return 0;
}

Clang
When I compile with x86_64 clang 18.1.0 with flags -O3 -std=c++23 I get the following assembly
test():                               # @test()

Which means : this function does nothing (it evens doesn't return).
Gcc
When the same code is compiled with x86_64 gcc 14.1 with flags -O3 -std=c++23 I get the following assemblby :
test():
        mov     eax, 2
        ret

which means : return 2.
My question
I'm confused as I thought that when a variable is undefined, the compiler is allowed to choose a path (based on whatever rule it wants) so I expected either 1 or 2 in the return value as gcc does, but I didn't explected an invalid function as clang does.
Can you please explain me what's the standard rule the compiler should follow when they test an undefined variable. And who's wrong  (my expectations, clang, gcc) ?.
I tried to get illumination by drinking a coffee. I'm now caffeinated, not illuminated.

It's Undefined Behaviour. Compiler is allowed to do anything with such code, no rules apply.

"so I expected" You should not expect anything - that's what Undefined Behaviour means. The compiler is allowed to do anything it wants.

Undefined behavior means that literally anything can happen. Unspecified behavior means that one of several undocumented behaviors may happen (but at least the program won't run off into the woods). Depending on the situation, accessing the value of an uninitialized variable with automatic storage duration could either lead to undefined or unspecified behavior and iirc C and C++ are different here, though I'm pretty sure that this particular example is explicitly undefined behavior in both languages.

Undefined doesn't mean that it happily gets to choose one or the other. It means it is allowed to catastrophically malfunction.

I personally like the outcome of Clang more. Undefined Behavior can hit you quite underhanded, especially if it looks like working in debugging. (MSVC fills every variable with test patterns in Debug mode - i.e. bools will always be initialized in Debug mode but may not in Release mode. Once, that made me head scratching because it worked always in the debug session but only sporadically in the Release.) Not to get any code for U.B. lines may focus your attention faster to the code to be fixed. Admittedly, a respective compiler message might do as well... :-)

It is your expectations that are wrong.   Accessing the value of an uninitialised variable of automatic storage duration gives undefined behaviour which essentially means the C++ standard does not impose any requirements or constraints on what happens. C++ compilers are permitted to give any outcome, whether that makes sense to you or not - they are permitted to return 1, return 2, return 0, return 42, or even reformat your hard drive, or do something different depending on phase of the moon.

Terminology fix: the variable is not undefined. It is defined, but uninitialized (causing undefined behavior as explained above).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

In short, accessing an uninitialized variable is erroneous behavior in C++26, and undefined behavior before that. It means that your code can be optimized out or do random nonsense, or crash, or anything else really. See the linked duplicates for details.

You should read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub including all the very nice articles linked at the end.
